# socket.send function in Python sending Nulls

Tags: python, sockets, send

I tried to send "Hello World" to simple server in c++.
I wrote this line :

```
self.soc.send("Hello World")
```

I checked what the server recieved and the result was : 'H', because the rest was : '\0','e','\0','l'....

Why the send function change my message?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would appear that your C++ code is not prepared to receive a 16-bit encoded (UTF-16 probably) string, and is expecting a byte-stream instead...

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your C++ code is not prepared to receive a 16-bit encoded (UTF-16 probably) string, and is expecting a byte-stream instead... – twalberg